# making modules independent from providers

Tags: terraform

I have the following code in my root module:

```
provider "vsphere" {
  user           = var.vsphere_user
  password       = var.VSPHERE_PASSWORD
  vsphere_server = var.vsphere_server

  # If you have a self-signed cert
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

module "kubernetes_cluster_vm_pool" {
  source = "./modules/kubernetes_cluster_vm_pool"
}

module "kubernetes_cluster" {
  source = "./modules/kubernetes_cluster"
}

module "someapp" {
  source = "./modules/someapp"
}
```

}

The first module requires the terraform provider for VMware vSphere, as such it will always attempt to connect to vSphere. However, my aim was to allow people to use this who did not necessarily want to use VMware, for example they only want to deploy someapp to a kubernetes cluster that is not underpinned by VMware virtual machines.

Changing the code such that it does not refer to the VMware provider still causes terraform to attempt to connect to VMware, obviously its still walking the directory structure and picking the kubernetes_cluster_vm_pool code up. One option is to run terraform init and then apply in the actual directory containing the someapp module source code, however - I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution than this ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally-speaking, there isn't any such thing as a provider-agnostic Terraform module except in the very limited case of a module that doesn't include any resources at all and exists only to do some calculations or other data wrangling using local values and output values.

However, the situation you've described is a good example of an opportunity for using [Module Composition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/composition.html) to use a module in different ways across multiple configurations, as described in the [multi-cloud abstractions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/composition.html#multi-cloud-abstractions) section.

The idea in that case is to write some modules which depend only on the Kubernetes provider and other modules that depend only on the provider for a particular system that can host Kubernetes clusters, and then in each configuration using these modules you can combine modules for a particular system with generic Kubernetes-only modules to deal with the differences between different underlying platforms.

The module composition guide includes an example of this using a hypothetical module that creates a Kubernetes cluster in Azure using the `azurerm` provider and another hypothetical module that expects a Kubernetes cluster hostname as an argument, without caring which underlying infrastructure is hosting that Kubernetes cluster:

```
module "k8s_cluster" {
  source = "./modules/azurerm-k8s-cluster"

  # (Azure-specific configuration arguments)
}

module "monitoring_tools" {
  source = "./modules/monitoring_tools"

  cluster_hostname = module.k8s_cluster.hostname
}
```

A separate configuration could then combine that same "monitoring tools" module with a vSphere-flavored Kubernetes cluster module to get an equivalent result with different underlying technology:

```
module "k8s_cluster" {
  source = "./modules/vsphere-k8s-cluster"

  # (vSphere-specific configuration arguments)
}

module "monitoring_tools" {
  source = "./modules/monitoring_tools"

  cluster_hostname = module.k8s_cluster.hostname
}
```

As long as this monitoring_tools module only depends on the Kubernetes provider and not on the `azure` or `vsphere` providers then it can be agnostic to the underlying infrastructure as you were hoping.

---

There is one further caveat to the above which unfortunately arises when passing objects created by one provider to another provider as above: until the Kubernetes cluster is created, the Kubernetes provider won't be able to initialize in order to plan whatever resources are in the `monitoring_tools` module. This is one situation where we can use Terraform's `-target` option during our initial setup to ask Terraform to focus on creating the Kubernetes cluster first, before trying to use it:

```
terraform apply -target=module.k8s_cluster
```

This extra option is only needed for initial bootstrapping, because on subsequent operations the cluster will typically already exist and so the Kubernetes provider and the underlying infrastructure provider can both initialize together.

If you end up doing this sort of thing a lot, you can remove the need for `-target` by decomposing the platform-specific parts and the generic parts into separate Terraform configurations which collaborate using data sources, in which case you can `terraform apply` the platform-specific infrastructure first, get that up and running, and then `terraform apply` the platform-agnostic parts once the cluster is operating. This is a different way to achieve the same result as using `-target`, which is typically easier to automate due to it not requiring any special Terraform arguments.

Comment: Martin, Many thanks for this and all the great advice you have provided over on the Hashicorp Terraform forum, it is much appreciated.